# AdoQuery.Filter with dates

Tags: sql, date, delphi, ms-access

So, I have a Query: `"Select * FROM Payments WHERE Day([PayDate])=Day(Date()) AND Month([PayDate])=Month(Date())"`

And I was wondering how can I do this in the `ADOQuery.Filter` propertie of the ADOQuery.

I know you can use "Ands" to put more than one condition, but I don't get the `Month(Date())` and `Day(Date())` thing in this.
I'm using an Access database btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADOQuery.Filter is not the same as SQL "WHERE" clause.

You need to calculate functions in SQL before using them.

Try to make like this:

```
ADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT *, Day([PayDate]) AS d, Month([PayDate]) AS m FROM Payments';
```

And then use "d" and "m" fields in ADOQuery.Filter

```delphi
uses DateUtils;

procedure FilterQuery;
var
  D: TDateTime;
begin
  D := Now;

  ADOQuery.Filtered := False;
  ADOQuery.Filter := Format('d = %u AND m = %u', [DayOf(D), MonthOf(D)]);
  ADOQuery.Filtered := True;
end;
```

Comment: I got some errors, in the `ADOQuery.Filter` line, my code is the same but I think it's a problem with the "%u" or the `DayOf`

Comment: If you can not compile, then add DateUtils unit to "uses".

Comment: The code Compiles but it's crash a few seconds after. This part of the code is the "OnActivate" propertie of the Form, I've identified in what part the program freezes, and is on the filter part. Also I got the error of invalid sentence or something like that

Comment: I'am sorry, but I don't have extrasensory abilities. Need more info.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was in a hurry. When I run the code like the one above, It runs but, stop working when reach the `ADOQuery.Filter := Format('d = %u, m = %u', [DayOf(D), MonthOf(D)]);` line. When I change that, it runs without a problem. I have DateUtils too. I got an EOleException, and it says: " The arguments are incorrect , they are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict". I tested it with some breakpoints, and it stopped after I set the `ADOQuery.Filtered` to true. Btw, ADOQuery here don't seems to have a `ADOQuery.CommandText` Propertie, instead, I used the `ADOQuery.SQL.Text`.

Comment: Aw, sorry for that. It is my mistake. Not 'd = %u, m = %u' but 'd = %u AND m = %u'